# What are the best practices to choose the provisioning method?

Tags: site-definition, provisioning

What are the best practices/ ideal scenario to choose the provisioning method?

1. Site Template
2. Web Templates
3. Site Definition

Comment: From 2010 Microsoft recommends WebTemplates, Vesa does a great comparison here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx

Comment: I personally prefer Provisioning Providers and Feature Stapling!